# Pygame UI clearing and updating

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

At the request of Furas, below are the segments of code in a Pygame Project that I'm currently working on. What I'm trying to get to happen is essentially like clearing everything visible on the previous window so I can start fresh with a new UI. When the code is run, and the "Start Game" button is pressed on the startup screen, the background colour updates, but everything that was previously rendered (the title and all of the buttons) remain on the screen. If anyone could offer any general pointers - or advice based off the code below - that would a great help!

---

#### The `game_loop` function:

This first part is where I need the screen to be cleared/updated. The `game_loop` contains more game logic, which is irrelevant to the current question, and what is pasted below is the only part of the function that interacts with the window.

```
new_surface = pygame.Surface((1,1))

def game_loop():
    
      global clicked_game
      global game_running
      clicked_game = True
      game_running = True
      
      if clicked_game == True:
        screen.fill( (0,0,0) )
    
      screen.blit(new_surface, (0,0))
      pygame.display.update()
```

---

#### User Interface Initialisation and Functions:

These are the rest of the functions which follow later on from the actual game logic in `game_loop`:

```
        def quit_game():
          pygame.quit()
          quit()
        
    
        def update_options():
          global clicked_options
          clicked_options = True 
        
        
        def button(window, msg, x_coord, y_coord, width, height, initial_colour, highlight_colour, button_action):
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        
            if x_coord + width > mouse[0] > x_coord and y_coord + height > mouse[1] > y_coord:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, highlight_colour, (x_coord, y_coord, width, height))
                if click[0] == 1:
                  button_action()
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, initial_colour, (x_coord, y_coord, width, height))
            
        
            button_Text = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
            text_Surf, text_Rect = text_objects(msg, button_Text)
            text_Rect.center = ((x_coord + (width / 2)), (y_coord + (height / 2)))
            window.blit(text_Surf, text_Rect)
        
        while play:
          
          for event in pygame.event.get():
              if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                play = False
        
          button(screen, "Start Game", 231, 236, 250, 50, e_m_light, e_m_lighter, game_loop)
          button(screen, "Options", 231, 336, 250, 50, e_m_light, e_m_lighter, update_options)
          button(screen, "Exit", 231, 436, 250, 50, e_m_light, e_m_lighter, quit_game)
          
          if clicked_options == True:
            #update title colour for testing purposes
            text_Surface = Font1.render('BlackJack Blast!', True, e_m_lighter)
          else:
            text_Surface = Font1.render('BlackJack Blast!', True, white)
        
          screen.blit(textSurface,(106,100))
          pygame.display.update()
```

---

#### Screenshots of the UI before and after pressing "Start Game":

[User Interface - Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwyjY.jpg)

[User Interface - After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trfWL.jpg)

---

I'm still a bit of a pygame novice, so if you're unsure of how to fix this specific problem, but recognise something else that could do with improving, or if you need any more information to develop a solution, please let me know!

Comment: use variables like `display_menu = True`, `display_game = True`, etc to control what elements you display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You blit all buttons all the times - in every loop - so why the shoud disaper ?

You can use variables like `display_menu = True`, `display_game = True`, `display_options = False` to control what elements display - silimiar to `clicked_options`.

But cleaner is to create separated `while True` loop  for every scene - `Menu`, `Game`, `Option`.

You can use functions like in example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47460947/1832058

It uses `front_page()`, `menu()` to run different `while True` loops for two different scenes.

Or you can create classes for differnt scenes/stages: [stage-example](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/stage-example/main.py)

---

You can see this on image:

[image: PyGame Schema #1]